# Are vector graphics slower than bitmaps in Android?

Tags: android, performance, graphics, bitmap, vector-graphics

I'm considering implementing vector graphics into my application, but I'm worried about the performance, since it seems natural that the vector graphics take more time to render themselves than (by contrast) static bitmaps.

Should I be worried about this factor, or does Android behave in a way that it shows no real difference?

Comment: Yes vector images are resource heavy so do not use a lot of them

Comment: Well, vector graphics require **CPU** time. In contra, images require **storage** space. Both require memory. So... your choice: **slow** or **heavy**?

Comment: I think if you need to display large resolution images that can be reproduced by vector (e.g. not photos) it is viable. Otherwise bitmaps still win.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at [this page](http://upday.github.io/blog/vector_drawables_optimisation/), you'll see that VectorDrawables will take a bit of time to render the first time and it is cached and very fast afterwards.

The time the initial rendering takes is directly proportionate to the size, so it is recommended to only use vector images up to 200 x 200.

Comment: Note that I don't follow up on my own recommendation: 1 part of the app I work on has a screen with almost fullscreen vector graphics. I don't notice any performance issues there and not a single user has complained about it.

Answer (score 2):

I just debugged an issue with my application where a single complex vector logo image was adding 1-2 seconds of Activity load time on Android 4.4 Kitkat, Samsung Galaxy SIII. I switch that particular vector graphic back to raster and restored the performance of my app.

Thus, I would say empirically that there is a potential performance penalty for using vector graphics on Android.